# Need to do calculations on turtle counts of 4 breeds in Netlogo

Tags: plot, netlogo

I am setting up an equilibrium simulation for a chemical reaction A + B <---> C + D and want to do a calculation of C*D/A*B (number of turtles) after each tick and add that value to a variable and divide that by the number of ticks run to get an average and then plot that running average.  I am able to do the calculation using the Monitor button on the interface screen but would like to plot and average  value vs a static value.  How do you perform a calculation in Netlogo and store the value?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you want memory (that is, access to previous values of something), then the easiest way is to use a variable to store the values. You can store the whole series as a list. Let's call the variable 'equilibrium'.

At the top of your code you need:

```
globals [equilibrium]
```

to tell NetLogo that the variable exists. Somewhere in your setup you should let NetLogo know this is going to be a list, using:

```
set equilibrium []
```

Then when you calculate you can store the current value at the front of the list with something like this (or `lput` if you want it at the end):

```
let calc count C * count D / (count A * count B)
set equilibrium fput  calc equilibrium
```

The average can be found with `mean`, as for any list. The advantage of having it at the front of the list is that it is always `item 0` for the plot.

In this particular case, since you just want the average you don't need the whole list. You could simply create a variable for the total (say cum-calc) and add the current value each tick:

```
set cum-calc cum-calc + calc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - will play around with this and see if I can do a plot with cum-calc / ticks